# Spring JPA primary key violation with cascade all on second call

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 classes:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String value;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private SubFoo subFoo;

  //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class SubFoo {
  @Id
  private String id;

  //getter setter
}
```

And my test create request is

```
{
    "value": "bar",
    "subFoo" : {
        "id" : "sub1"
    }
}
```

My aim is now the following: if I POST that body the first time, I want to have both entities persisted, as neither the Foo nor the SubFoo exists. To make this work without further lines of code, I added the cascade ALL option.

When that body is now POSTed the second time, it should just take the "sub1" and bind it to the second entity. But instead Hibernate tries to persist a SubFoo with id "sub1" a second time, which leads to a primary key violation.

My question is, is there any way to declare the entities, in a way I can post my JSON twice with hibernate automatically recognize when to persist or when to just bind, without doing manual checks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see this link maybe it could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775827/insert-new-entity-that-has-an-unidirectional-many-to-many-relationship-generate